# Fredholm integral equation of the second kind - no homogeneous cases anywhere?

Tags: integration, integral-equations, homogeneous-equation

I'm trying to solve this **homogeneous** Fredholm integral equation of the second kind for $y(x)$.

$y(x) = \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \ln \left( \frac{1}{x-t} \right) y(t) dt$

I'm aware of Liouville-Neumann series expansions but I cannot find anything online that covers any method for homogeneous equations. The methods & tutorials I have read seem to only cover the inhomogeneous variety, namely:

$y(x) = \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \ln \left( \frac{1}{x-t} \right) y(t) dt + f(x)$

Either my equation is unsolvable, its solution is somehow implied within its inhomogeneous counterpart, or I've just missed something. I have found a possible solution at https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FredholmIntegralEquationoftheSecondKind.html (Equation 2) but cannot tell what $F(t)$ represents.

Could anyone please help point me towards a solution?

Comment: Are you allow to use Fourier analysis for this problem? One can observe that for your kernel, say $K(x,t) = \ln\left(\frac{1}{x-t}\right),$ that $K(x,t) = \widehat{K}(x - t),$ where $\widehat{K}(z) = \ln\left(\frac{1}{z}\right).$ Then your problem becomes, $y(x) = (\widehat{K} \circledast y)(x),$ where $\circledast$ denotes convolution. There is also a description on the following Wikipedia page here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fredholm_integral_equation#Equation_of_the_first_kind

Comment: Yes, I can use anything since this isn't for a class.

Comment: I've seen that page but it only lists the inhomogeneous equation. I'm trying to find the homogeneous solution. If I use the formula on that page, a trivial solution (y = 0 everywhere) results.